# `git bisect run` with a bash function

Tags: bash, git, git-bisect

Is there a convenient way to write a bash script to run `git bisect run`, where the bisect command used is itself a bash function?  If my function is named `step`, it appears that `git bisect run step` and `git bisect run bash -c step` are both unable to see the function.

My script currently looks something like

```sh
function step {
  # Do a bunch of steps here
}

if [[ $_ == $0 ]]  # Test if the script is being sourced
then
  git bisect start
  git bisect bad bad-commit
  git bisect good good-commit
  git bisect run bash -c ". $0 && step"
  git bisect log
fi
```

This uses a gross hack of making the script source itself in the command passed to `git bisect run`, and which means I have to check if the script is currently being sourced before attempting to execute the `git bisect` commands.

I suppose I could just split the bash function into a seperate script, buts there a better way to do this all in one file?

Comment: You can [export a function to the environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/can-i-export-functions-in-bash)…although I would just move the contents of your `step` function into a separate script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either export the function with `export -f step` or you can use `set -a` to export everything in your script.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, I think.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a convenient way to write a bash script to run `git bisect run`, where the `bisect` command used is itself a bash function?

You will be able to re-test your script with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) since [`git bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bee6e7a8f9951e486827bdebd14ab6d93b50a1bf/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup> becomes a builtin.

No more bash script.

See [commit 0da4b53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0da4b538e40f38f2ee7adc625cac18ae0d8df4d1), [commit 252060b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/252060be77f1d9ba7696bb3540f61451e147bf8b), [commit 8962f8f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8962f8f8887c15b3e55ebc348a2490290a55d8a5), [commit 461fec4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/461fec41fa79803c367ccaf11f713d6c67ba709f), [commit f37d0bd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f37d0bdd42d08602204760f42f48cb4d77b251bf) (10 Nov 2022) by [Đoàn Trần Công Danh (`sgn`)](https://github.com/sgn).
See [commit 2445d34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2445d34fb9e426c9b4e55ffffa6a32f536b7ff05) (11 Nov 2022) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
See [commit 049141d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/049141dce971bdbb85b3c6d12aae7254e7ddbe68) (15 Nov 2022), and [commit 5512376](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5512376ae14b07bb3c71c3ea7b4a181dd0fb4172), [commit 929bf9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/929bf9db28e617e55b52bdd307f3d44ceeb3e978), [commit bdd2aa8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdd2aa8a8bc46efce4a300d3cd6e169d89e99bc8), [commit 982fecf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/982fecf7c195d47c50cd397db303d262d2af88f6) (10 Nov 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
See [commit 73fce29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73fce29427071e53d2650d7f201cf44d3c941e3b), [commit df63421](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df63421be927c689bbd9384d503768c0515063c4) (10 Nov 2022) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bee6e7a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bee6e7a8f9951e486827bdebd14ab6d93b50a1bf), 14 Dec 2022)</sup>

For instance:

> ### [`bisect--helper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5512376ae14b07bb3c71c3ea7b4a181dd0fb4172): emit usage for "git bisect"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Đoàn Trần Công Danh</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> In subsequent commits we'll be removing "git-bisect.sh" in favor of promoting "bisect--helper" to a "bisect" built-in.
>
> In doing that we'll first need to have it support `git bisect--helper <cmd>` rather than `git bisect--helper --<cmd>`, and then finally have its "`-h`" output claim to be "`bisect`" rather than "`bisect--helper`".
>
> Instead of suffering that churn let's start claiming to be "[`git bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5512376ae14b07bb3c71c3ea7b4a181dd0fb4172/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup> now.
> In just a few commits this will be true, and in the meantime emitting the "wrong" usage information from the helper is a small price to pay to avoid the churn.
>
> Let's also declare `"BUILTIN_*"` macros, when we eventually migrate the sub-commands themselves to `parse_options()` we'll be able to re-use the strings.
> See [0afd556](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0afd556b2e1a8b5028d27cdede92bbab74a714da) ("`worktree`: define subcommand -h in terms of command -h", 2022-10-13, Git v2.39.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b9b634ca5e931941938c93bd233d9c6848fd7b2) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63bba4fdd86d80ef061c449daa97a981a9be0792)) for a recent example.