# How to 'git bisect run ' with ZSH function

Tags: git, zsh, bisect

Previously in BASH I used 'git bisect run' with 'script.sh param1 param2'.
I use ZSH now and I converted scripts to functions in a single functions-file, for easier editing. Sourced functions-file.

How can I 'git bisect run' with ZSH function (not separate script file)?

Tried 'git bisect run zsh -c "sourced-function param1 param2 param3"' but that gives "zsh:1: command not found: sourced-function", although in zsh I can run "sourced-function".

Found this [`git bisect run` with a bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66663362/git-bisect-run-with-a-bash-function) mentioning that in Git 2.40+  git bisect becomes a builtin - but did not understand if that affects my problem.
Other suggested answer, exporting functions, seems impractical especially in ZSH.

EDIT: Later found [zsh and parallel: How to use functions. It says command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61948652/zsh-and-parallel-how-to-use-functions-it-says-command-not-found) which seems related but IDK how to apply that in feasible manner. Not clear how to activate env_parallel and where.

I do not have 50 points to ask for clarification in comments.

PS: Seems that proper approach is to use zsh path for functions as separate files and autoload, not to source single file with functions. But I prefer this way, so question remains.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @svlasov `git bisect run` requires a program (a shell script, e.g.) but the OP wants to run a shell function. The solution is either call the function from a shell script or run the very shell like in the linked question.

Comment: "*…in Git 2.40+ git bisect becomes a builtin - but did not understand if that affects my problem.*" It doesn't. "*…exporting functions, seems impractical…*" Nothing impractical. Close to be the only solution.

Comment: @phd Thanks but IDK how to export in ZSH and use that here. can you please offer a full answer?

Comment: I cannot give an answer because I use Bash. I'd use a shell script or copy the solution from the linked question -- 'zsh -c "function"'

Comment: As for exporting functions from zsh see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22739630/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bzsh%5D+export+function

Comment: Um. I assume this has nothing to do with git, but with zsh not loading the functions from wherever you defined it, when its run non-interactively. (Similar to bash not loading aliases and .bashrc if run non-interactively). Did you try something like `git bisect run zsh -c 'source "$HOME"/.zshrc; sourced-function param1 param2 param3'` yet?

Comment: @Jay That did the trick, thanks. That could be Answer, if you write it. I tried zsh -c before but without source, thinking I already have those functions working.. Not clear to me whay this was needed.

Comment: @TimSO Glad to hear it worked. I added it as answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Shells usually won't execute their function-loading startup scripts when run in non-interactive mode.

For `zsh` you should be able to manually load those scripts/functions using the `source` built-in command:

```
git bisect run zsh -c 'source "$HOME"/.zshrc; sourced-function param1 param2 param3'
```

Comment: Using this, I see 2 issues: 1. how will "$HOME" be expandeed within single quotes (double quotes may be used with $HOME but this leads to another issue) 2. I would like to use this as ** zsh -c "source $HOME/.zshrc; $@" ** where $@ should be sourced-function and it's parameters. I see a a substituiton and sourced-function run but complains that it has no parameters. Why? Thanks.

Comment: **1**.: `$HOME` will be passed verbatim from git to zsh and only *zsh* will then expand the variable (it doesn't see the single quotes from the git command line, it just gets passed the string). Expanding earlier is okay too. Result should be same. **2**.: I'm not sure what's going on there. Are you trying to pack the bisect command into a script and have the script accept the sourced-function+params as arguments? Maybe try `zsh -c "set -x; source $HOME/.zshrc; $@"` for more insight. Maybe the quotes are causing trouble with `$@`, do you get the same result with `$*` instead of `$@`?

Comment: 1. I run all from a function. Somehow single quotes don't work, but double do. 2. Yes, putting bisect into function. Previous solution/answer was the main one and this is just saving time. So, $@ would list `sourced-function+params` but run only `sourced-function` w/o params. But, $* really runs `sourced-function+params` OK, thanks. Only caveat is that it looses any quotes or backslashes of those params, so `file name.ext` is NOK, file not found.

Comment: Spaces part seems can be resolved with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668649/how-can-i-keep-quotes-in-bash-arguments.